# How to deploy docker image in minikube?

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, minikube, docker-desktop

I have a container image that I want to run in minikube. My conainer image has MySQL, redis and some other components needed to run my application. I have an external application. My external application need to be connected to this MySQL server. The container image is written such that it starts the MySQL and redis server on its startup.

I thought I could access my MySQL server from outside If I run the container image inside docker daemon in minikube after setting the env as mentioned as below,

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

But this didn't help me since the MySQL server is not accessible in 3306 port.

I tried the second method that creating a pod,

I created the deployment using the below yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: c-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: c-app
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 3306
    targetPort: 5000
  type: LoadBalancer

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: c-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: c-app
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: c-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: c-app
        image: c-app-latest:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

After creating the deployment, containers are creating. As I said before my image is designed such that it starts the MySQL and Redis server on startup.

In docker desktop while running the same image it starts the servers, opens ports and stays still and I can also perform some operations in the container terminal.

In minikube, it starts the servers and once it has started the servers, the minikube marks the pod's status as completed and tries restarting it again. It didn't open any ports. It just starts and restarts again and again until eventually it results in "CrashLoopBackOff" error.

**How I did it before:**

I have a container image that I previously was running in docker desktop. It was running fine in docker desktop. It starts all servers and it establishes connection with my external app. It also provides an option to interact with the container terminal.

**My current requirements:**

I want to run the same image in minikube that I ran in docker desktop. Upon running the image it should open ports for external connection (say port 3306 for MySQL connection) and I should be able to interact with the container through,

```
kubectl exec -it <pod> -- bin/bash
```

More importantly I don't want the pod restarting again and again. It should start one time, start all servers and open ports and stay still.

Sorry for the long post. Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Do you have a separate StatefulSet and Service for the MySQL database (and then you could `kubectl port-forward service/mysql 3306`)?  Running multiple parts in a single container, especially a mix of stateful and stateless parts, isn't usually a best practice; if you really have all of this in a single container, with no mounted storage, and 3 replicas, then you have three separate disconnected MySQLs and three separate disconnected Redises.

Comment: I have MySQL, Redis and Cstore in a single container image. I don't have them separately in individual container images. These 3 components have to start at the startup. Previously I have run this image in docker desktop without any issues. Now I am searching for an alternative to docker desktop. That's why I am trying minikube with the same image that I have used in docker desktop.

Comment: Is there any way that I could run these three components in minikube without having separate image for each of the components? I have storage mounts also for each of these components. It would be very helpful, if you can tell me how to make this image run in minikube. Suggestions in the yaml file are appreciated!

Comment: @Ram : Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.